# Estimation of ranks of log-returns via copula

Tags: estimation, copula, log-returns

I have successfully chosen and estimate a copula for the ranks of the log-returns of my actions. My question is, **since I have worked with the ranks instead of directly the log-returns** (in order to be in $[0,1]$) **how can I simulate new data for the log-returns from my copula?**

To be more clear, here is the code commented:

```
library(copula)
library(quantmod)
#stocks chosen: Microsoft, General Electric
stocks<-c("MSFT","GE")
start="1996-01-01"
end="2000-12-31"
ALL<-NULL
dailyLogReturns<-NULL
cours<-NULL
for(i in stocks){
  #get quotes from Yahoo
  temp<-getSymbols(i,from=start,to=end,auto.assign=FALSE)
  #store adjusted quotes
  #adjusted quotes are used due to split actions in the past
  cours<-cbind(cours,Ad(temp))
  #calculate daily log return for adjusted quotes
  dailyLogReturns<-cbind(dailyLogReturns,coredata(dailyReturn(Ad(temp),type='log')))
}
colnames(cours)<-stocks
colnames(dailyLogReturns)<-stocks
#ALL is the ranks of the log-returns, in [0,1]
ALL<-pobs(dailyLogReturns)

#Here is the graph of the daily log-returns
plot(dailyLogReturns)
```

[image: Plot of bivariate log-returns]

```
#Here is the graph of the ranks of the daily log-returns
plot(ALL)
```

[image: Plot of bivariate ranks]

```
#Estimate the copula
#here i only show the Student, others have been tried without success.
#degres of freedom have been chosen independently
tc<-tCopula(param=c(0),dim=2,dispstr="un",df=7, df.fixed=TRUE)
ftc <- fitCopula(tc,ALL,method="mpl")

#Goodness of fit for the copula, p-value is about 40%
time.start=Sys.time()
GOF<-gofCopula(tc, ALL, estim.method="mpl", simulation="mult")
Sys.time()-time.start
(GOF$p.value>0.05)

#New data sample from the copula
Copula.data<-rCopula(1000,tCopula(0.417,df=7))
plot.new()
par(oma=c(1,1,1,1),mar=c(1,1,1,1))
plot(Copula.data,main="",xlab="",ylab="",col="red",pch="*");points(ALL,col="blue",pch="*")

#Here is the plot: new data from copula (red) vs initial data (blue)
```

[image: Comparaison of data from copula (red) vs initial data (blue)]

### **So, what have I tried?**

I used the quantile function based on 1000 observations of daily log-returns to calibrate and 263 observations for back-testing

```
nb.calibration<-1000
nb.backtesting<-nrow(dailyLogReturns)-nb.calibration
a<-matrix(0,nb.backtesting,nb.calibration)
b<-matrix(0,nb.backtesting,nb.calibration)
for(i in 1:nb.backtesting){
  j=1+i;k=nb.calibration+i
  a[i,]=dailyLogReturns[j:k,1]
  b[i,]=dailyLogReturns[j:k,2]
  rmtc<-quantile(a[i,],Copula.data[,1])+quantile(b[i,],Copula.data[,2])
}

plot(rmtc,type='l')
lines(dailyLogReturns[,1],col='red')
lines(dailyLogReturns[,2],col='blue')
#Here is the plot obtained: new data from the copula (black), Microsoft (blue), GE (red)
```

[image: Comparaison of log-returns generated vs historical]

### **Finally: Am I doing the right thing, is that correct ?**

**Sources:**
- [Estimation of Portfolio Value-at-Risk using Copula](http://www.rbi.org.in/scripts/PublicationsView.aspx?id=13336)
- [Some nonparametric tests for copulas with emphasis on goodness-of-fit tests](http://www.uclouvain.be/cps/ucl/doc/stat/documents/slides_kojadinovic_200511.pdf)

Comment: Good question. what progress have you made so far? do you still need some assistance?